# Import API not working in sisense

Tags: rest, api, post

I was trying to use the dashboard import API from v1.0 which can be found in the REST API reference. I logged in to http://localhost:8083/dev/api/docs/#/ , gave the correct authorization token, and a dash file in the body, and a 24 character importFolder and hit the Run button to fire the API. It returns 201 as HTTP response, which means the request was successful. However, when I go back to the homepage, I don't see any new dashboard imported in to the said folder. I have tried both cases, where the importFolder exists (already created manually be me), and does not already exist, where I expect the API to create it for me. Neither of these, however, create/import the dashboard

[image: This is my HTTP request and body]

[image: This is my HTTP response]

Answer (score 0):

A few comments that should help you resolve this:

1. When running the command from the interactive API reference (`swagger`) you don't need the authentication token, because you're already logged in with an active session.
2. Make sure the `json` of your dashboard is valid, by saving it as a `.dash` file and importing via the UI
3. The `folder` field is optional - if you leave the field blank, the dashboard is imported to the root of your navigation/folders panel.
   *If you'd like to import to a specific folder, **you'll need to provide the folder ID, not its name,*** which can be found several ways such as using the `/api/v1/folders` endpoint, where you can provide a `name` filtering field and use the `oid` property of the returned object as the value for the `folder` field in the `import` endpoint.
4. If you can't get this to work still, use chrome's developer tools to look at the outgoing request when you import from the UI and compare the request (headers, body and path) to what you're doing via `swagger` in order to find the issue.